# Rails Gem 5.0.0 install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an error with installing Rails. I am using 64-bit Windows 10 and I already install the MSYS2 dev kit and Ruby. Here is the error message from the Command Prompt:

> C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:457:in 'try_do': The compiler
>   failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to
>   install development tools first.
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:588:in 'try_cpp'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1095:in 'block in have_header'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:945:in 'block in checking_for'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in 'block (2 levels) in postpone'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in 'open'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in 'block in postpone'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in 'open'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:347:in 'postpone'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:944:in 'checking_for'
>           from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1094:in 'have_header'
>           from extconf.rb:3:in ''
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/nio4r-1.2.1/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1

Any advice? Any help or tips?

Thanks for your time and help,
David

Comment: I had this issue earlier this weekend -- just installed Ruby for the first time. I ended up uninstalling it and re-installing, and when I got to the MSYS2 part I pressed ENTER. I'd pressed 1 the first time and I think skipping over the dev toolchain was a mistake.

This may help: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059

Comment: you can also install rails on Windows Subsystem for Linux, which is my preferred method!

Answer (score 3):

`You have to install development tools first.`

This is a mandatory to have the development tools installed. You can find more instruction reading this [article](https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059)